# Linq, EF Core - group by on one field and use other field to get list of data from other table

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a output from Linq in particular format.
This question has been rephrased -

SQL View- SomeView

```
    Id T_Id
    4   2 
    6   5
    6   7
```

SQL table - User

```
    T_Id  fname lname
    2     mary   smith
    5     john    pope
    7     steve   blair
```

SomeView is QueryType, I used DbQuery to map it.

```
    public class SomeView
    {
       public int Id {get; private set;}
       public int T_Id { get; private set; }

       public User User { get; set; } //can't navigate here
    }

    public class User
    {
       public int T_Id { get; set; }
       public string fname {get; set;}
       public string lname{get; set;}

       public SomeView SomeView{ get; set; } //can't navigate here
    }
```

There are no foreign key constraint defined in database as SomeView is SQL view. 
You can't use Navigation with QueryType. So mapping between User and SomeView is not possible or I don't know how to do.

```
     public class SomeViewModel
     {
        public int Id { get;  set; }
        public List Users{get; set;}
     }

finally my linq in progress - 

    from t in SomeView
    group new {t} by t.Id into grp
    select new SomeViewModel{
       Id = grp.Key,
       Users = grp.Select(x => x.t.User).ToList()
       //need help here to get Users based on T_Id
      }
```

Final API data output should be in following format.

```
[{
  "Id" : "4",
  "users":[{
         "T_Id": 2,
         "fname": "mary",
         "lname": "smith"
      }]
},
{
  "Id" : "6",
  "users":[{
         "T_Id": 5,
         "fname": "john",
         "lname": "pope"
      },
      {
         "T_Id": 7,
         "fname": "steve",
         "lname": "blair"
      }
      ]
}]
```

Comment: Your tables imply *many-to-one* relationship from `SomeTable` to `User`. Hence `List<User> Users` in the view model makes no sense - each record in `SomeTable` can have 0 or 1 `User`. You'd better show the **entity model** - with proper *navigation properties* the LINQ query should be trivial - something like `db.SomeTable.Select(t => new SomeViewModel { Id = t.Id, User = t.User })`.

Comment: But SomeTable is a view. Can't use HasMany on QueryTypeBuilder.

Comment: modified question. SomeViewObj is QueryType used DbQuery to map it. I can't map it with HasMany on QueryTypeBuilder.

Comment: Still my first comment applies. `SomeViewObj` is the **many** side of the relationship, so you need a single **reference** navigation property `public User User { get; set; }` mapped with `HasOne` and `T_Id` mapped with `HasForeignKey`. This is how we access data in EF Core queries. If you want regular LINQ, take a look at [C# join clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Comment: You can't use Navigation properties for QueryType SQL View. I am adding details to my questions above

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First, I think you can use any serializer to convert your objects to the format you want.</strike>

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
```

Second, back to your question, here is the code. However, you need to add " around your variables and get rid of string concatenation I added for readability. Also, this code is so specific to your problem and for more generic solution go for the first approach.

```
var mainData = string.Join(',', data.Select(x => $" {{ {nameof(x.Id)} :  {x.Id}, " +
                                                           $"{nameof(User)}s: " +
                                                           $"[ {string.Join(',', x.Users.Select(y => $"{{ {nameof(User.T_Id)} : {y.T_Id} }}"))}]" +
                                                           $"}}"));
var result = $"[{mainData}]" ;
```

As you changed the question, I updated my answer. So, you need to first join someView and user to get them together and then group by someView.id. Here is the code

```
        var someViewsUsersJoin = someViews.Join(users, l => l.t_id, r => r.t_id, (someView, user) => new {someView, user});

        var result = someViewsUsersJoin.GroupBy(x => x.someView.id).Select(x => new SomeViewModel()
        {
            Id = x.Key,
            Users = x.Select(y => y.user).ToList()
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, But I need help with Linq query. I rephrased my question hopefully it's easy to understand now.

Answer (score -1):

Finally Resolved it this way -

```
 public class SomeView
{
   public int Id {get; private set;}
   public int T_Id { get; private set; }

}

public class User
{
   public int T_Id { get; set; }
   public string fname {get; set;}
   public string lname{get; set;}
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
   public int Id { get;  set; }
   public List<User> Users{get; set;}
}

   from t in SomeView
   join u in User on v.T_Id equals u.T_Id
   group new {t, u} by t.Id into grp
   select new SomeViewModel{
      Id = grp.Key,
      Users = grp.Select(x => x.u).ToList()
  }
```

That was easy :)